# dirtyFields with itemview

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a master/detail application that I'm building with backbone marionette.  as the user clicks the master rows, the detail will show the row details.

users need to be able to edit the row.  I'd like the notify them if they try to 'leave' the row before saving.  I was thinking that I'd use the dirtyFields plugin for this functionality.

Has anyone else used these together?  when I swap out my itemview, how do I initialize the plugin?  when I close the view, is there anything I should think about to clean up the view?

any thoughts would be appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that plugin, but you should be able to take advantage of the `onShow` and `onRender` methods of Marionette's views to do this.

I wrote an article that discusses the use of jQuery plugins with Backbone a while back, which would hopefully help you out:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/